# How to read input from keyboard instead of file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I have the below python snippet

```py
@click.argument('file',type=click.Path(exists=True))
```

The above command read from a file in the below format

```sh
python3 code.py file.txt
```

The same file is processed using a function

```py
def get_domains(domain_names_file):
    with open(domain_names_file) as f:
        domains = f.readlines()
    return domains
domains = get_domains(file)
```

I dont want to read it from file , I want to provide a domain as an argument while executing in terminal , the command will be

```sh
python3 code.py example.com
```

How should I rewrite the code .

Python Version : 3.8.2

Comment: Look into argparse.

Comment: Remove the `type` from the argument declaration. See [docs](https://pocoo-click.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arguments/)

Comment: @rdas can you make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click.argument` by default creates arguments that are read from the command line:

```
@click.argument('file')
```

This should create an argument that is read from the command line and made available in the `file` argument.

See the docs & examples [here](https://pocoo-click.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arguments/)

Comment: changing it into @click.argument() , will work ? I couldnt understand

Comment: Yes. The `type` that you're passing enforces that the value is a valid file path. If you want to read the data directly, you can remove that. see the example here: https://pocoo-click.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arguments/#basic-arguments

Answer (score 3):

I realised you're using the [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/arguments) library.
Since you want to pass the 'domain'/website as an argument, you can just input it as a string. If you remove the 'type' parameter from your decorator, it would make the type STRING by default.

> The most basic option is a simple string argument of one value. If no type is provided, the type of the default value is used, and if no default value is provided, the type is assumed to be STRING.

Solution:
`@click.argument('domain')`

Answer (score 0):

You may use `argparse`:

```
import argparse

# set up the different arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some nasty description here.')
parser.add_argument("--domain", help="Domain:   www.some-domain.com", required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.domain)
```

And you invoke it via

```
python your-python-file.py --domain www.google.com
```